# New Version of Phusion Passenger Not Used

Tags: ruby, macos, passenger, rbenv

After the update to OS X El Capitan, I've been trying to get my development environment to work again. My PHP sites are running, but I can't bring up my Ruby on Rails ones. The Phusion people recomended going to their latest version before offering any help. So I ran Brew upgrade passenger. I ran normally and exited with this message:

```
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/passenger/5.0.24: 3,149 files, 140.4M
```

When I run passenger version, I get:

```
Phusion Passenger version 4.0.57
```

When I run which passenger, I get:

```
/Users/curt/.rbenv/shims/passenger
```

When I run rbenv which passenger, I get:

```
/Users/curt/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/bin/passenger
```

When I run echo $PATH, I get:
    /Users/curt/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

I've got to figure out why I had a duplicate /usr/local/bin.

When I run rbenv local where I've been running the other commands, I get 2.2.0.
I've done a rbenv rehash. Is there some step I've missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I have two copies of passenger: one I installed with brew and another I installed with gem. When I did "gem update passenger", passenger version returned the latest version.